# User-defined function for string to date conversion

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, plpgsql

I have csv file date consisting a column date, which is in text datatype

```
Date
(text)
-----------
 date1
 date2
 date3
```

I need to change the column into date datatype. SO I tried this method.

```
create or replace function fn_date_conversion (
 get_column text
) 
    returns table (
        
        datecolumn date
    ) 
    language plpgsql
as $$
begin
    return query 
        SELECT TO_DATE(get_column,'YYYY-MM-DD')
        from tblsalesdata;
end;
$$

SELECT fn_date_conversion(date)
```

but it throws an error

> ERROR:  column "date" does not exist
> LINE 1: SELECT fn_date_conversion(date)

When I try to make function without parameter with following query it work

```
   create or replace function fn_date_conversion (
 
) 
    returns table (
        
        datecolumn date
    ) 
    language plpgsql
as $$
begin
    return query 
        SELECT TO_DATE(date,'YYYY-MM-DD')
        from tblsalesdata;
end;
$$
```

but I need to return parameter so I can convert date dynamically not statically as I have other date column which are in text type too. How to fix this?

Comment: Why the overhead of a PL/pgSQL function? A view would achieve the same thing

Comment: Please elaborate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the the column name is dynamic, then you need to use dynamic SQL

So you need function like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo(colname text, tblname text)
RETURNS TABLE(datecol date)
AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY EXECUTE
    format($_$SELECT to_date(%I, 'YYYY-MM-DD') FROM %I$_$,
           colname, tblname);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT * FROM foo('colname','tblsalesdata');
```

Comment: That double quote didn't work and the solution you gave is for static query only but I want  dynamic function which can be used for other table too.

Comment: @Awesome - sorry, you didn't write this, then you need to use dynamic SQL.